# How to Make a JFrame unmovable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How to make a `JFrame` unmovable?

I am working on an application that needs the use of multiple frames, using various mouse events for each of them. The application requires the frames to stay where they are defined to be.

Thank You for your answers.

Comment: You know.. this sounds like something my boss would say to me. And you're not my boss Mohit. You're not my boss.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: You can't guarantee that everyone using your app will have the same screen resolution.  I sense an ADA lawsuit in the making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach for making the frame unmovable is to make it undecorated

```
myFrame.setUndecorated(true);
Color color = UIManager.getColor("activeCaptionBorder");
myFrame.getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(color, 4));
```

Comment: Thank you it works. But is there another way where the title bar stays.

Comment: Not really, approaches that use a listener to ground the frame give a "jumpy" result when you attempt to move the frame. As an aside, you could give the undecorated frame a border to make it more frame-like

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
myJFrame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
         public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            setSize(1024,768);  // or whatever your full size is
         }
         public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
            setLocation(0,0);
         }
      });
```

Comment: It works but eventually the frame will not stay concreate.

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* the best you can do is remember their positions and move them back on mouse release. This is a very bad idea, and you shouldn't do it. If the user wants to move frames around, let them.

Comment: Somehow I think someone is going to end up with an app that is constantly snapping back to its position every time it's moved by 1 pixel...I just hope it's not me.